# Systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in <?> being skipped

Tags: boot

SYSTEM INFORMATION

- Operating system Ubuntu Linux 20.04.3

Since upgrading over to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, I have seen these in my syslog. Quite a lot of stuff being skipped. They do not look like errors, but are these warnings healthy?

**What do you think I should do about all these?**

```
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in ShPlymouth Boot Screen being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch being skipped.
kernel: [    4.693593] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in System Slice being skipped.
kernel: [    4.980208] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
kernel: [    4.990001] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
kernel: [    4.997748] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
kernel: [    5.319608] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
kernel: [    5.319688] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in LXD - agent - 9p mount being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in LXD - agent being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Authentication service for virtual machines hosted on VMware being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Service for virtual machines hosted on VMware being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Timer to automatically fetch and run repair assertions being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Unix socket for apport crash forwarding being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Login to default iSCSI targets being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Pollinate to seed the pseudo random number generator being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC Remote Quota Server being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in fast remote file copy program daemon being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Automatically repair incorrect owner/permissions on core devices being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Wait for the Ubuntu Core chooser trigger being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Thermal Daemon Service being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu Advantage reboot cmds being skipped.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Auto import assertions from block devices being skipped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings are not a problem.
Take this one for example:
fast remote file copy program daemon being skipped.
this is rsync.
The systemd control file  (systemctl cat rsync) gives this information:

```
[Unit]
(...)
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf
```

and

```
systemctl status rsync
● rsync.service - fast remote file copy program daemon
(...)
  Condition: start condition failed at Tue 2022-05-31 21:57:10 CEST; 1 day 16h ago
             └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf was not met
```

so the service exists, it is ready to run but if the sysadmin does not setup what it has to do by creating a rsyncd.conf file, it is not started.
This is a good thing because it saves resources.

Outputting a warning is an information for the sysadmin wondering why there is a daemon but it does not run.